# Approximating profile likelihood confidence intervals when I only have a score function and not a likelihood

Tags: confidence-interval, modeling, quasi-likelihood, profile-likelihood

I'm working on a modeling problem where I can define a score function that looks a lot like a binomial likelihood, but the model isn't really binomial. I'd like to use profile likelihood to estimate confidence intervals and covariance for two parameters of interest, among many other nuisance parameters. But I don't have a real likelihood and I don't know how to estimate the variance in this score function. And so I don't know how to construct a normalized Gaussian approximation that I can treat like a profile likelihood for confidence intervals.  Advice?

[Edited to provide more detail]. I'm doing a many-parameter fit of a complex model to a bunch of different binary measurements. The data come from an infectious disease transmission study, where we have prevalence measurements on a few different days from the start of the study in a few different cohorts. The data are thus $\{Y_t^C,N_t^C\}$ for day $t$ in cohort $C$, positive outcomes (infected) on each day $Y_t$, and total number sampled each day $N_t$. We model the prevalence for each cohort and time as a probability $p_t^C(\theta)$ defined by model parameters $\theta$.

If the data and model predictions were independent, then it would be reasonable to model the log-likelihood as a sum of binomials,

$\log L(\theta|\{Y_t^C,N_t^C\}) \propto \displaystyle \sum_C\sum_t \left(Y_t^C \log\left(p_t^C(\theta)\right) + (N_t^C-Y_t^C)(1- \log\left(p_t^C(\theta)\right) )  \right)$

Since the data and model predictions aren't independent at each time point, this isn't the right likelihood (which is intractable to write down). But, it is a good score function, so I'm using it as the score in an optimizer to find best-fit parameters $\hat{\theta}$.

Knowing everything here is at best approximate, I'd like to estimate approximate confidence intervals with some kind of plausible statistical interpretation, even if only asymptotically under an assumption about how the score maps onto a real likelihood.

[Edited with updated thinking.] <s>If I knew how to estimate the variance for this score, I could assume normality, and then calculate a two-parameter confidence ellipse in the standard way for profile likelihood intervals. But I don't know how to estimate the variance of the score.</s>

Only two of the parameters are of primary scientific interest, and the model is expensive to evaluate, and so I think this is a good use case for profile likelihood. *I think* if I'm willing to accept that as a likelihood, then I can just do the standard thing of sweeping over the two parameters, and defining the confidence ellipse with a likelihood ratio test and two degrees of freedom. (NB: my earlier text assumed I needed a variance estimator, but this score isn't approximating a normal, but rather is a binomial approximation with the wrong covariance structure to the real likelihood, and all the relevant terms are evaluated here already.)

I feel like I might be missing something obvious, like asking the optimizer to return a hessian or something and inverting that.

I'm using `optim` in R but could also use the `stats4::mle` wrapper if it'll make my life easier. Advice?

Comment: Can you give some details, for example, how does the score function look like?

Comment: Thanks. I edited to give more detail on the score and how I'm thinking about the problem.

Comment: Having only the score function makes this look similar to quasi-likelihoos, so I added that tag.